# Penultimate letter of word

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner, cpu-word, letter

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Word: ");
    String word = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Pe : " + word.substring(word.length() + 1 ));
```

I find last char but i need find one before last.

Answer (score 0):

The second to last character is at index `length-2`:

```
char penultimate = word.charAt(word.length() - 2)
```

If you want it as a string:

```
String penultimate = word.substring(word.length() - 2, word.length() - 1)
```